# pokeapi how to filter only the first 151 pokemon?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, pokeapi

I'm trying to get the urls of the first pokemons and consume their data to transform into a dataframe, but I can't separate these urls and make a request for each pokemon or bring all 151 at once.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
```

```
request_pokemon = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151=0")
request_pokemon = request_pokemon.json()
```

I have to consume all this pokemon data and put on a pandas DataFrame, but i dont know how to consume the pokeapi one by one or all together

I tried loops with while and for and tried a def(), but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I visit the URL, I see the first 151 pokemon. Are you struggling to turn it from a json to a dataframe?

Comment: I'm trying to get the urls of the first pokemons and consume their data to transform into a dataframe, but I can't separate these urls and make a request for each pokemon or bring all 151 at once.

Answer (score 1):

According the API documentation https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon-section (section **Resource Lists/Pagination**) you can add `?limit=150&offset=0` to URL to get first 150 pokemons:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150&offset=0"
data = requests.get(api_url).json()

print(len(data["results"]))
```

Prints:

```
150
```

Comment: Too bad there is no Pokemon tag, you'd miss only 999 more votes to the gold badge :p

Comment: There's [tag:pokeapi] but only 51 questions... no gold badge :(

Comment: You can have it with 20 votes per question, go catch them all :p